# How do you get only the top 30 biggest bubbles to show up in a bubble chart?

Tags: tableau-api

[This is what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bg5NU.png)

[This is what I have now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDq7i.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is drag the same dimension that's responsible for those beautiful bubbles onto the filter shelf. Once it's there you can select Top from the Edit Filter dialog box that appears, then choose By field and enter however many you'd like.

[image]

In the example above, I'm using Superstore Sales. There is a bubble for each State, but I'm about to filter them to just the top 30 States, but total sales.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

It would depend on what you have on the Marks card, but this will help hopefully :

[Tableau Desktop screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rf4CQ.png)

If that doesn't help, can you expand the screenshot so the Marks card, Rows shelf and Columns shelf are visible.